# Dropbox snyc with Onedrive

Tags: windows, dropbox, onedrive

I want to sync my dropbox with my onedrive. Actually i want to make onedrive my primary storage.

Example: Someone send me dropbox file link and i will open the link and click save to my dropbox then it should go in my onedrive.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could create a scheduled task that runs every hour or so which copies all file and folder changes from Dropbox to OneDrive

1. Take note of your Dropbox and OneDrive folder paths
2. Create an advanced task and under actions create a new action with robocopy.exe as program and the following line as arguments:

   `"DropboxPath" "OneDrivePath" /MIR`

E.g. `"C:\users\user\Dropbox" "C:\users\user\OneDrive" /MIR`

Save it and right click the scheduled task and run it to sync it. It'll run in the interval that you've chosen.